# Bindable attribute doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I've extended the standard `TextBox` control to support padding. It works, except that the IDE does not persist the padding into the designer class.

Code:

```
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public new Padding Padding
    {
        get
        {
            return padding;
        }
        set
        {
            padding = value;
            OnPaddingChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Strangely, if I change the property name to `MyPadding` or anything else, it suddenly works. What causes this problem?

Comment: Try public Padding @Padding

Comment: Seems like your only option is to choose an other name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you shadow a base class property just to change some attributes, don't use own backing field, but base property itself, like this

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[Browsable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Bindable(true)]
public new Padding Padding
{
    get { return base.Padding; }
    set { base.Padding = value; }
}
```

P.S. While the code above solves the persistence problem, I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "it works" because there must be a some good reason for the corresponding `Control` property being specifically shadowed in the `TextBoxBase` class in order to be hidden.

Comment: Since padding is by default not supported for TextBox control, I use winapi calls in PaddingChanged event handler.

Comment: So your solution works, but do you also know the reason why the base property itself must be used? Why can't IDE work with custom property implementation?

Comment: It's hard to be explained, there are many rules involved in what get serialized and what not. But think logically, it's quite confusing a derived class to have the same property as the base class and have a different value, and not only confusing. Imagine `var tb = new YourTextBox(); var tb1 = (TextBox)tb;` and `tb.Padding` is different than `tb1.Padding`.